# Why this line break is occuring?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I'm new to javascript. I want to print the output in the same line without any line break using `<h1>` tag.

Generally, my output is coming in single line, but when I'm joining that with `<h1>` tag, the output appearing in different lines.

Here's my code.
Guide me through.

```
https.get(url, function(response) {
    console.log(response.statusCode + 'OK');
    response.on('data', function(data) {
      const weatherData = JSON.parse(data);
      const temp = weatherData.main.temp;
      const desc = weatherData.weather[0].description;
      console.log(temp);
      res.send(
        '<h1>The temperature in London is ' + '<h1>' + temp + '<h1> ° Celsius.'
      );
    });
  });
```

[image]

Comment: This is an HTML problem, not a JavaScript problem. You can nest `h1`'s, but I'd be curious, why? If nesting `h1`'s is not your goal, wrap the whole string in `h1` tags (opening and closing).

Comment: sorry, i'm new in this field. and thanks for solution

Comment: No problem! @Youssef AbouEgla's answer is what I'd recommend.

Comment: @JakeWorth No you may not nest heading elements. That is invalid.

Comment: @Rob huh! I got that idea from MDN's heading elements page: "Permitted parents: Any element that accepts flow content; don't use a heading element as a child of the <hgroup> element — it is now deprecated." Included in this list are the headers themselves: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Flow_content.

Comment: @JakeWorth I got my information from the validator (cause I was too lazy to look up the spec): *Heading cannot be a child of another heading.*

Comment: @Rob nice. What validator is that? Perhaps we can agree that such nesting doesn't make sense, or present a semantic meaning to the user or browser.

Comment: @JakeWorth [There's only one](https://validator.w3.org/nu/) (well, [two](https://validator.w3.org/)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your code with

```
res.send(
   `<h1>The temperature in London is ${temp} Celsius</h1>`
);
```

If you want to style the temp use `<span style="color: red;">${temp}</span>`

Answer (score 1):

`h1` is a block element, whose default is 100% width. You can use a span tag inside it for the variable, and optionally you can add a class to style that variable:

```
res.send(
   '<h1>The temperature in London is ' + '<span class="your_class">' + temp + '</span>° Celsius.</h1>'
);
```